# ResolveInfo - check if is default launch intent or not

Tags: android, package-managers, android-package-managers

**What I do**

I'm retrieving a list of all installed apps like following (for a launcher like app):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

// flag PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER will set ResolveInfo.filter (not documented, but tested)
// many examples use flag == 0, but then the filter is always null
List<ResolveInfo> ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
if (ril != null) {
    for (ResolveInfo ri : ril) {
        // I need this info!
        // ri.isDefault is always false...
        boolean isDefault = ri.isDefault || ril.filter.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    }
}
```

So far, this works. But some apps like samsungs phone app do not respect that they should only flag one activity with `Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT`. Here's what the categories for the two activities in samsung's app look like:

```
ActivityInfo{cd007eb com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity}
    filter:
        0 = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
        1 = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
        2 = "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
        3 = "android.intent.category.APP_CONTACTS"

ActivityInfo{3e9ba8d com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity}
    filter:
        0 = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
        1 = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
        2 = "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
```

**Requirements**

- I need a list of all activities a launcher like app like mine can launch
- I need the info if a `ResolveInfo` is the one that is launched if I use the apps package name only like if I use the intent retrieved by following command: `pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)`. This one is what I call the default launch intent in this post

**Question**

How can I find out reliably if a `ResolveInfo` belongs to the default launch intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

*This solution is useable as long as you assume that only some apps register multiple default activities.*

- get all `ResolveInfos` like in my question
- create a `HashMap` and insert package names and number of entries in list
- use the `HashMap` to determine if you even need to check if the `ResolveInfo` belongs to the default activity or not
- if you need to check, make the slow check for this `ResolveInfo`

**Code**

```
List<ResolveInfo> ril = ...;
HashMap<String, Integer> packageCountMap = getPackageCountMap(uniqueRil);
for (ResolveInfo ri :: ril) {
    boolean isDefault = isDefaultIntentForPhoneApp(packageCountMap, ri);
    // use this info...
}
```

*Helper function:*

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> getPackageCountMap(List<ResolveInfo> ril) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    ResolveInfo ri;
    Integer count;
    if (ril != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ril.size(); i++) {
            ri = ril.get(i);
            count = map.get(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (count == null) {
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            map.put(ri.activityInfo.packageName, count);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

public static boolean isDefaultIntentForPhoneApp(PackageManager pm, HashMap<String, Integer> packageCountMap, ResolveInfo ri) {
    boolean isDefault;

    // count how often the package name exists => 1x => then the activity must be the default one, no need to do any check
    Integer count = packageCountMap.get(ri.activityInfo.packageName);
    if (count == null || count <= 1) {
        isDefault = true;
    }
    // otherwise get default activity and compare it
    else {
        Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        ComponentName cn = i.resolveActivity(pm);
        isDefault = cn != null && cn.getClassName().equals(ri.activityInfo.name);
    }
    return isDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `queryIntentActivities` as follows:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Based on the documentation for **MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY**:

> Resolution and querying flag: if set, only filters that support the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT will be considered for matching. This is a synonym
>   for including the CATEGORY_DEFAULT in your supplied Intent.

Comment: this is the same as what I do already. I add the categroy, so adding the flag you suggest does not change anything. The problem is, that there may be apps that register multiple default activities and I need to find out which one is the "real" default in the sense of which activity is launched if I start the default activity with the app's package name only (e.g. with following intent: `pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);`)

Comment: @prom85 Looking at your requirement, seems like you are looking for activity with `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` rather than `CATEGORY_DEFAULT `. Is it correct?

Comment: Does not make a difference for samsung's app (both activities have the launcher and default flag). I added a requirements area in my question to make more clear what I want to have